# Lotus Notes Table, default settings

Tags: lotus-notes

I am a Lotus Notes client user (8.5.x and 9.01).

I would like change the default setting for the table.

I don't like the default proposed from Lotus Notes:
a) Minimum height to 0
b) Row spacing to 0
c) Column spacing to 0
d) Border color to black
e) Vertical Align to top

Every time I create a new table I always change the default to
a) Minimum height to 0,4
b) Row spacing to 0,15
c) Column spacing to 0,15
d) Border color to silver
e) Vertical Align to center

Do you know how to set the table default?

note: atm I will copy and paste from a draft message...this is not a real elegant way to fix it!

[Image to show you the table properties](https://prnt.sc/h04vi4)

Comment: Did you mean specifically in an email, or any time you use a table in any application? I don't believe there's a way to set it across all applications. No idea why someone downvoted this by the way.

Comment: I think it was downvoted because it is a Super User question, not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not change the default settings.
You could create a blank table and store it in a document somewhere, then copy it into place when you need it.

However, this question does not belong on Stack Overflow, ut should been asked on Super User.